# Pycharm folder disappear

Tags: python, pycharm, mac

Столкнулся с проблемой в Pycharm (mac 14 pro m3 pro)
Открываю проект и видна папка с кодом:[image]

После запуска скрипта и принудительного стопа
Папка с проектом просто пропадает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы вернуть папку нужно или переключиться на другое окно и вернуться или нажать на кнопку "Reload all from disk"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить и из за чего такое происходит ?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык